# Using jq to filter dataset from The Mathematics Genealogy Project

Tags: json, jq

With this Json Data set.

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "students": [],
      "advisors": [
        258
      ],
      "name": "Archie Higdon",
      "school": "Iowa State University",
      "subject": "74—Mechanics of deformable solids",
      "thesis": "Stresses in Moderately Thick Rectangular Plates",
      "country": "UnitedStates",
      "year": 1936,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "students": [],
      "advisors": [
        258
      ],
      "name": "Donald Hill Rock",
      "school": "Iowa State University",
      "subject": null,
      "thesis": "Finite Strain Analysis in Elastic Theory",
      "country": "UnitedStates",
      "year": 1939,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "students": [],
      "advisors": [
        258
      ],
      "name": "William B. Stiles",
      "school": "Iowa State University",
      "subject": null,
      "thesis": "Solutions of Clamped Plated Problems by Means of Functions Derived from Membrane Characteristic Functions",
      "country": "UnitedStates",
      "year": 1945,
      "id": 6
    }
]

}
```

I was wondering how I can use jq in order to find people who graduated from Georgia Tech with a non empty list of students? As in, I want to find all students who graduated from Georgia Tech who went on to advise students themselves.

Comment: In addition to following the basic [mcve] guidelines, it is usual for questions on SO to include some indication of the strategy or program you've tried.  Also, your example doesn't seem to include anyone with students, or indeed anyone from Georgia Tech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming simplified json like this which has some values matching the conditions you mention

```
{
  "nodes": [
    { "students": [2, 3], "advisors": [],  "name": "Person 1", "school": "Georgia Tech", "id": 1 },
    { "students": [],     "advisors": [1], "name": "Person 2", "school": "Georgia Tech", "id": 2 },
    { "students": [],     "advisors": [1], "name": "Person 3", "school": "Georgia Tech", "id": 3 }
  ]
}
```

You can prune nodes to only people at "Georgia Tech" with

```
.nodes |= map( select( .school == "Georgia Tech" ) )
```

You can prune nodes to people with non-empty students with

```
.nodes |= map( select( .students | length > 0 ) )
```

You can combine the conditions with `and`

```
.nodes |= map( 
   select( (.school == "Georgia Tech") and (.students | length > 0) ) 
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY6xDoJAEER7vmJyFZcQI9CZYGtrYWcoLtwGMHCnHNog3457GAuMBYnb7czOvL3cpmljrCaHZ4ZWXUMEABw1VPQhwo0rKmsbZBnEgWxX1gonKiohoYz2fn/XZHqOoyFT9hX22EpIBHKaBu4Sc7vY4eyLMUB8Il5LIqR5BKH0o3a2mzXeOaVa4kUcqXPWIBZ89P7Fq4tX2Kk1qzHG6BfD9/EsGLGHfjGSFYzkT0a6gpFiZEQejC8)

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for.